# How to access the first neighbor of a node in NetworkX?

Tags: python, networkx

I created a graph of `TestClass` objects in NetworkX. I have two `TestClass` objects `obj1` and  `obj2` and I want to connect their first neighbors.

#### Code

```python
first_node = [node for node in G.nodes() if node==obj1][0]
second_node = [node for node in G.nodes() if node==obj2][0]                
G.add_edge(first_node.neighbours[0], second_node.neighbours[0])
```

I get an error message that `TestClass` object has no attribute `neighbors`.

How do you access these two objects as nodes in the Graph to work with their neighboring nodes?

Comment: Is `G.neighbours(first_node)` what you are looking for perhaps? See: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.neighbors.html

Comment: Yes, you're right. I had forgotten about accessing nodes in this way :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neighbors are accessed using the method [`Graph.neighbors(n)`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.neighbors.html), where `n` is a node.

Since `G.neighbors` returns an iterator over the neighboring nodes, to use a list accessor, you would first need to wrap the iterator in a `list` initializer.

```
G.add_edge(list(G.neighbors(first_node))[0], list(G.neighbors(second_node))[0])
```

A cleaner way would be to call `next()` on the iterators, which avoids creating new list objects and eliminates the index accessors.

```
G.add_edge(next(G.neighbors(first_node)), next(G.neighbors(second_node)))
```